# What are Html.Validate and Html.ValidateFor methods for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm finding it hard to find out helpful information about ASP.NET MVC's validation HTML helpers - Html.Validate and Html.ValidateFor.

Has anyone worked with these methods? what are they for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

see this post for an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581344/how-does-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-2-actually-work/1583887#1583887)

> If there are situations where you
>   don't actually want a validation
>   message to visually appear for each
>   field (i.e. by using
>   Html.ValidationMessage), but would
>   rather allow a summary to be the sole
>   source of validation error messages
>   (i.e. by using
>   Html.ValidationSummary), you still
>   need some way to "trigger" the
>   validation to occur for the specific
>   fields you want it to.
>   This can be achieved by using the
>   Html.Validate/Html.ValidateFor<> 
>   methods within your view. Those
>   helpers won't render anything, but
>   will simply register the specified
>   field for client-side validation.

Comment: Are they only for client side validation?

Comment: sorry, I couldn't say it to 100%. the documentation is not so precise about this. It only says as a remark to enable clientsidevalidation. but what about testing it quickly. 

I would think, that your validation is fired on the client and also on the server when posting back. because your validation rules are defined as property attributes. do you need client validation only? why then not use an jquery validation library ;-)

Comment: I can't get it to work, too. I am to stupid to pass the right parameters. Could any pro help us? ...Shay, for what problem you intend to use this method?

Comment: I got an answer at the asp.net site forums. Turned out that these methods are used only for client side validation and only works for "automatic validation" that is added by data annotations or metadata classes.